# Php, composite pattern, is it bad when "item" knows about "basket"

Tags: php, composite

Given this code:

```
class Basket
{
    public function getAdata()
    {
        return array(1,2,3,4);
    }

    public function getItem()
    {
        return new Item ($this);
    }
}

class Item
{
    public function __constructor (Basket $p)
    {
        $p->getAdata();
    }
}
```

They say it is bad because `Item` knows about `Basket`, because `Item` should be a standalone living thing. If I rewrite it like this:

```
class Basket
{
    public function getAdata()
    {
        return array(1,2,3,4);
    }

    public function getItem()
    {
        return new Item ($this->getAdata());
    }
}

class Item
{
    public function __constructor ($data)
    {
    }
}
```

It is better. Why?

Comment: What happens when you want to use a bag instead of a basket?

Comment: I remove the "Basket" hint :) but Im getting understand this argument

Comment: If this sort of thing worries you, then use an Interface. That's pretty much exactly what they're for. You'd typehint the interface instead of the concrete class.